# Best way to make water for unity

Tags: unity

I want to create a game in unity and make my own water for it. I am having difficulty because Unity won't run waves or water simulations. I want to create a water ripple current effect type of thing. What would be the easiest way to do this? Should I use shaders?

Comment: Every question that starts with "*Best way to*..." is generally both too broad and subjective, it is generally also dependent on what you want to do specifically. You could do ripples and running water by baking an animated normal maps or bump maps in Blender for example.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about Unity, not Blender.